# how to calculate the last day of the current month?

Tags: android, android-calendar

Start up fragment I need to put in the two text two dates. Start date and end date. Start Date - the current date and I put it. End date - the last day of the current month. I do not know how to calculate. help me please.

Date start:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
dateBegin.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
```

end date, the last day of this month, I do not know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Good luck.